# foreach Loop add items to combobox

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

I want to loop through a list of person object, every person has a few qualities that differs, like one person has a book, the other person has a table, but all the persons have the same name, id, email, and last name. When I loop through it, it adds every person that has a different quality to my combobox. Where I only want it to add one person's .ToString into the combobox. I want to be able to use the combobox.selectedItem to get qualities of that item later on. Here is my code:

```
foreach (Person personObj in _listAllData)
{
    if (!cboSelectClient.Items.Contains(personObj.ID))
    {
        cboSelectClient.Items.Add(personObj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will help, thanx in advance.

Comment: If you only put the result of the `ToString` method into the combo box, `SelectedItem` will only contain strings. Note, however, that by default, you should be able to add the person objects themselves to your combo box (which should then automatically display their `ToString` return value).

Comment: If i change the statement to cboSelectClient.Items.Add(personObj); It adds all the persons into my combobox

Comment: I only want it to display one of the persons

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are trying to do correctly:

```
cboSelectClient.Items.Add(personObj.ToString());
```

adds the entire person Object expressed as a single string to the combo box.
In the `if` clause, you are checking only for the `ID` of the person object.

So your `if` clause is looking for a string that matches only the `ID` of the person but your combobox contains elements listed as `ID + other details of the person`. They will never match unless some person object has just his `ID' listed in the combobox.

You may have to iterate through each item in the combobox and check if each item has the 'ID' you are looking for as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

This linq will be able to help u

```
 Foreach (var personObj in _listalldata.group(v=>v.id).select(s=>new { id = s.First().id}).tolist())
  {
                if (!cboSelectClient.Items.Contains(personObj.id))
                {
                    cboSelectClient.Items.Add(personObj.id.ToString());
                }
            }
```